Overprint messing with block environment
Is there a reason that the text in the block inside the overprint environment moves up and is there a way to globally correct this?
MWE:
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[block=fill]{metropolis}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame title}
    Always present text
    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>
        \begin{block}{Theorem}
            I'm moved up in the overprint environment.
        \end{block}
    \end{overprint}
    \begin{block}{Theorem}
            I am where I belong.
        \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Output:


You could avoid the problem by using the updated fork of metropolis, the moloch theme, instead of metropolis:
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[block=fill]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame title}
    Always present text
    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>
        \begin{block}{Theorem}
            I'm moved up in the overprint environment.
        \end{block}
    \end{overprint}
    \begin{block}{Theorem}
            I am where I belong.
        \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Beamer blocks are also overlay-aware. You could simply use \begin{block}<1> instead of \onslide etc. This will also avoid the extra empty line:
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[block=fill]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame title}
    Always present text
        \begin{block}<1>{Theorem}
            I'm moved up in the overprint environment.
        \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Theorem}
            I am where I belong.
        \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



How do I use the moloch theme on Overleaf? If I download the package from CTAN, it only has .dtx and .ins files but no .sty files.

You could ask the overleaf support to move your project to texlive 2024. This should automatically have moloch installed.
